# ¿Cómo ocultar el ribbon de un reporte con devexpress?

Tags: windows-forms, devexpress, reporting

¿Qué tal?

Quiero ocultar el ribbon de mis reportes al momento de ejecutarlos pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

¿Alguien sabe cómo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la respuesta en el [Ticket de soporte de DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T315176/hide-or-remove-toolbar-reports), puede usar este código:

```
ReportPrintTool reportPrintTool = new ReportPrintTool(new XtraReport());
reportPrintTool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.File, false);
reportPrintTool.Report.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.ExportFile, false);
reportPrintTool.ShowPreviewDialog();
```

Como recomendación personal, si se trata de productos de DevExpress, es mejor que consulte directamente la documentación oficial de los controles de DevExpress y/o los tickets de soporte de DevExpress.